# ASP.NET GridView inside Repeater Control

Tags: asp.net, gridview, repeater

I have checked all available articles and none seem to help me.

I have a GridView that is located inside a Repeater control.  The data that populates the Gridview is dynamic and is grouped by a SectionID.  I need for each repeated GridView to list the data rows grouped according to their SectionID.

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Public Sub GrabRepeaterData()
    Dim connstr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyString").ToString()
    Dim ss As New SqlConnection(connstr)
    Dim sqlStr As String = "SELECT SectionID, Name FROM Table1"
    Dim selectCMD As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlStr, ss)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dataAdapter As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand = selectCMD
    dataAdapter.Fill(dt)
    selectCMD.Dispose()
    dataAdapter.Dispose()
    ss.Close()
    ss.Dispose()

    dt.Columns.Add("Column1")
    dt.Columns.Add("Column2")
    dt.Columns.Add("Column3")
    dt.Columns.Add("Column4")
    dt.Columns.Add("Column5")
    dt.Columns.Add("Column6")
    dt.Columns.Add("Column7")
    dt.Columns.Add("Column8")

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim SectionID As String = ""
        SectionID = row("SectionID")

        Dim Column1 As String = ""
        Dim Column2 As String = ""
        Dim Column3 As Boolean
        Dim Column4 As String = ""
        Dim Column5 As String = ""
        Dim Column6 As String = ""
        Dim Column7 As Boolean
        Dim Column8 As Boolean
        Dim ProgConn As String = ""
        ProgConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyString").ToString()
        Dim ProgSqlQuery As New SqlConnection(ProgConn)
        Dim ProgResults As New SqlCommand("SELECT [Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4], [Column5], [Column6], [Column7], [Column8] FROM Table2 WHERE SectionID = @SectionID ORDER BY Column4 DESC", ProgSqlQuery)
        ProgResults.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SectionID", SectionID).Value = SectionID
        ProgSqlQuery.Open()
        Dim rProg As SqlDataReader = ProgResults.ExecuteReader()
        While rProg.Read()
            If Not rProg("Column1").Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
                Column1 = CStr(rProg("Column1"))
            End If
            If Not rProg("Column2").Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
                Column2 = CStr(rProg("Column2"))
            End If
            If Not rProg("Column3").Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
                Column3 = CStr(rProg("Column3"))
            End If
            If Not rProg("Column4").Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
                Column4 = CStr(rProg("Column4"))
            End If
            If Not rProg("Column5").Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
                Column5 = CStr(rProg("Column5"))
            End If
            If Not rProg("Column6").Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
                Column6 = CStr(rProg("Column6"))
            End If
            If Not rProg("Column7").Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
                Column7 = CStr(rProg("Column7"))
            End If
            If Not rProg("Column8").Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
                Column8 = CStr(rProg("Column8"))
            End If
        End While
        rProg.Close()
        ProgResults.Dispose()
        ProgSqlQuery.Close()
        ProgSqlQuery.Dispose()

        row("Column1") = Column1
        row("Column2") = Column2
        row("Column3") = Column3
        row("Column4") = Column4
        row("Column5") = Column5
        row("Column6") = Column6
        row("Column7") = Column7
        row("Column8") = Column8

        row.EndEdit()
        dt.AcceptChanges()
    Next


    CustomInfoRepeater.DataSource = dt
    CustomInfoRepeater.DataBind()


End Sub

Protected Sub CustomInfoRepeater_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles CustomInfoRepeater.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
        Try

            Dim grdVw As GridView = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("CustomInfoGridView"), GridView)
            grdVw.DataSource = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataTable).Rows
            grdVw.DataBind()
            Dim CustPanel As UpdatePanel = DirectCast(CustomInfoRepeater.Items(0).FindControl("CustomInfoPanel"), UpdatePanel)
            CustPanel.Update()

        Catch
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="CustomInfoRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="download-box3">               

                </h2>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="CustomInfoPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="CustomInfoGridView" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="CustomInfoGridView" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        DataKeyNames="Column1" GridLines="None" RowStyle-Height="40px" EnableViewState="False"
                        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" RowStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Column1" />
                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="35px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="newIcon" runat="server" Width="31px" CssClass="myGridImage"
                                        Visible="false" ImageUrl="images/new.png" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="35px" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" AlternateText="Delete" ImageUrl="images/xmark.png"
                                        OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?')"
                                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Column1") %>' CommandName="Remove" CssClass="myGridImage">
                                    </asp:ImageButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="30px" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="GenComUpdateButton" runat="server" CssClass="buttonsmall" Text="update"
                                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Column1") %>' CommandName="GenComments"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="50px" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Impact" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="30px"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Image ID="statusIcon" runat="server" Width="20px" CssClass="myGridImage" Visible="false"
                                        ImageUrl="" AlternateText="*" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="50px" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50px" HeaderText="Files" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="filesIcon" runat="server" Width="23px" CssClass="myGridImage"
                                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Column3") %>' CommandName="Download" Visible="false"
                                        ImageUrl="images/pdf.png" AlternateText="*" />
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="AttachAssetsBtn" runat="server" CssClass="buttonredsmall" Text="upload"
                                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Column1") %>' CommandName="Uploads" Visible="false"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="50px" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Column3" HeaderText="Summary" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                                <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50px" HeaderText="Reviewed" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Image ID="reviewedIcon" runat="server" Width="23px" CssClass="myGridImage" Visible="false"
                                        ImageUrl="images/checkmark.png" AlternateText="*" />
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="reviewedCheckBox" runat="server" CssClass="inputtext" Visible="false"
                                        AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="GenComCheckUpdate" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="50px" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Column4" HeaderText="Updated" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ItemStyle-Width="75px">
                                <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Column6" Visible="false" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Column7" Visible="false" />
                        </Columns>
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                            <span class="data-none">No Comments have been added to this section.</span>
                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="EmptyRowStyle" />
                        <PagerStyle CssClass="PagerStyle" BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedRowStyle" BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True"
                            ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <EditRowStyle CssClass="EditRowStyle" BackColor="#999999" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltRowStyle" BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <hr />
    </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use DataRowView in ItemDataBound event to get all data from sql query as a table. Like (DataRowView)drv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem; int sectionId = drv["SectionID"];

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from the code is you are merging two datasources into one. Then binding it to the Repeater and then fetching the datasource for GV from the repeater DataItem and binding it to the GridView.

What I would suggest is keep the datasources separate and do it in two steps:

1: Bind the repeater to just the SectionID i.e. data returned by SELECT SectionID, Name FROM Table1

2: In the Repeater ItemDataBound, get the SectionID and fetch data with the query you have in ProgResults. Then bind that to the GV.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with gbs. Here's how you can do it:

In the markup, add a hidden field inside repeater, outside the updatepanel:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="CustomInfoRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSectionID" Value='<%# Eval("SectionID")%>' runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblName" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <div class="download-box3">
            </h2>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="CustomInfoPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<%-- Rest of the markup goes here --%>
```

Rewrite `GrabRepeaterData()` sub only to populate the repeater:

```
Public Sub GrabRepeaterData()
    Dim connstr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyString").ToString()
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connstr)
        conn.Open()
        Dim sqlStr As String = "SELECT SectionID, Name FROM Table1"
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlStr, conn)
        Dim adapter As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
        adapter.Fill(dt)
    End Using

    CustomInfoRepeater.DataSource = dt
    CustomInfoRepeater.DataBind()

End Sub
```

In repeater's ItemDataBound, find the `HiddenField`, find it's value, find the `GridView` inside `UpdatePanel`, populate it this way:

```
Protected Sub CustomInfoRepeater_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles CustomInfoRepeater.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
        Dim sectionID As Integer = 0
        Dim hdnSectionID = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("hdnSectionID"), HiddenField)
        Dim CustomInfoPanel = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("CustomInfoPanel"), UpdatePanel)

        If (CustomInfoPanel IsNot Nothing AndAlso hdnSectionID IsNot Nothing AndAlso Integer.TryParse(hdnSectionID.Value, sectionID)) Then

            Dim CustomInfoGridView = TryCast(CustomInfoPanel.FindControl("CustomInfoGridView"), GridView)

            If (CustomInfoGridView IsNot Nothing) Then
                Dim connstr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyString").ToString()
                Dim dt As New DataTable

                Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connstr)
                    conn.Open()
                    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT [Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4], [Column5], [Column6], [Column7], [Column8] FROM Table2 WHERE SectionID = @SectionID ORDER BY Column4 DESC", conn)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SectionID", sectionID)
                    Dim adapter As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
                    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
                    adapter.Fill(dt)
                End Using
                CustomInfoGridView.DataSource = dt
                CustomInfoGridView.DataBind()
            End If

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```